# iOS TCP/IP over USB with linux side

Tags: ios, linux, usb, tcp

I have question about TCP/IP connection over USB between iOS device and linux station, without enabling personal hotspot (tethering usb).

Comment: You don't have any comment ?

Answer (score 1):

You can connect to a TCP socket running on your iPhone over USB using iproxy. It is part of libusbmuxd.

If you're on Linux, your best bet is to install https://github.com/libimobiledevice/libplist/, https://github.com/libimobiledevice/libusbmuxd and  https://github.com/libimobiledevice/libimobiledevice from source.

Once your iPhone trusts your PC, you can run `iproxy [device port] [PC port]`. Any connection to `localhost:[PC port]` will then be forwarded to the [device port] running on your iOS device.

Comment: It's not authorized by apple, to use librairy like libimobiledevice :)

Comment: @MarouaneLanouari That’s arguably the best part